# SMS broadcast receivers don’t work after phone restart

Tags: java, android, android-intent

We are trying to build our autoresponder app with SDK 26 as a target version.

We have 2 `PhoneStateReceivers` in our app (see code below).

Also we are requesting permissions:

```
android.permission.READ_SMS
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

and user accept it.

But after phone restart and before the user unlocks the device (lock screen) both SMS broadcast receivers don’t work.

Relevant **AndroidManifest.xml** part:

```
<receiver android:name="com.lemi.callsautoresponder.callreceiver.DynamicPhoneStateReceiver" android:directBootAware="true" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" />
<receiver android:name="com.lemi.callsautoresponder.callreceiver.PhoneStateReceiver" android:directBootAware="true" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
              <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER"/>
              <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
          </intent-filter>
          <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
              <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.GSM_SMS_RECEIVED"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          </intent-filter>
          <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">                 
              <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED"/>
              <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.sic"/>
          </intent-filter>        
</receiver>
```

Relevant part in **Application.java**

```
public void registerPhoneStateReceiver() {
   Log.i(TAG, "register PhoneState receiver");
   _phoneReceiver = new DynamicPhoneStateReceiver();
   IntentFilter intentFilter1 = new IntentFilter();
   //intentFilter.addAction(PhoneStateReceiver.SMS_RECEIVED);
   intentFilter1.addAction(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
   intentFilter1.addAction("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");
   intentFilter1.setPriority(0x7fffffff);
   intentFilter1.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
   appContext.registerReceiver(_phoneReceiver, intentFilter1);

       IntentFilter intentFilter2 = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
       intentFilter2.setPriority(0x7fffffff);
       intentFilter2.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
       appContext.registerReceiver(_phoneReceiver, intentFilter2, "android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS", null);

       IntentFilter intentFilter3 = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.GSM_SMS_RECEIVED");
       intentFilter3.setPriority(0x7fffffff);
       intentFilter3.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
       appContext.registerReceiver(_phoneReceiver, intentFilter3, "android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS", null);

}

public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.info(TAG, "received sms");

  }
}

public class DynamicPhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.info(TAG, "received sms");

  }
}
```

Comment: Is this happening on a specific device/Android version?

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful http://babe.ilandroid.com/broadcast-receiver-not-working-after-device-reboot-in-android.html

Comment: Thanks, will look at it, but generally Everything work if we build with target version low than 26 With SDK 26 as a target it doesn’t work We have both android. permission .RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED and  BootCompletedReceiver
And it works
But SMS is not received
Calls received- SMS NOT

Comment: @M.Gin no update on this?  I'm facing similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the below permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

You have to register a receiver for boot completed with two actions.

**LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED** action for **Nougat and upper devices**.

**BOOT_COMPLETED** action for **Below Nougat devices**.

```
<receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

This `BootCompletedReceiver` will fire when the **phone reboots**. Within this `BootCompletedReceiver` class, you have to register all of your **Broadcast Receivers** programmatically. So that, all the broadcast receivers start working.

Comment: We have both android. permission .RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED and  BootCompletedReceiver
And it works
But SMS is not received
Calls received- SMS NOT

Everything work if we build with target version low than 26
With SDK 26 as a target it doesn’t work

Comment: @M.Gin Please check my answer again. I have added a new action and let me know it's working or not.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml add this line into intent filter.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: We have both android. permission .RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED and  BootCompletedReceiver
And it works
But SMS is not received
Calls received- SMS NOT

Everything work if we build with target version low than 26
With SDK 26 as a target it doesn’t work